# Is preprocessing file with awk needed or it can be done directly in R?

Tags: r, csv, awk

I used to process csv file with awk, here is my 1st script:

```
tail -n +2 shifted_final.csv | awk -F, 'BEGIN {old=$2} {if($2!=old){print $0; old=$2;}}' | less
```

this script looks for repeating values in 2nd column (if value on line n is same as on line n+1, n+2 ...) and prints only first occurrence. For example if you feed following input:

```
ord,orig,pred,as,o-p
1,0,0,1.0,0
2,0,0,1.0,0
3,0,0,1.0,0
4,0,0,0.0,0
5,0,0,0.0,0
6,0,0,0.0,0
7,0,0,0.0,0
8,0,0,0.0,0
9,0,0,0.0,0
10,0,0,0.0,0
11,0,0,0.0,0
12,0,0,0.0,0
13,0,0,0.0,0
14,0,0,0.0,0
15,0,0,0.0,0
16,0,0,0.0,0
17,0,0,0.0,0
18,0,0,0.0,0
19,0,0,0.0,0
20,0,0,0.0,0
21,0,0,0.0,0
22,0,0,0.0,0
23,4,0,0.0,4
24,402,0,1.0,402
25,0,0,1.0,0
```

Then the output will be:

```
1,0,0,1.0,0
23,4,0,0.0,4
24,402,0,1.0,402
25,0,0,1.0,0
```

**EDIT:**
I've made this a bit challenging adding 2nd script:

The second script does the same but prints last duplicate occurrence:

```
tail -n +2 shifted_final.csv | awk -F, 'BEGIN {old=$2; line=$0} {if($2==old){line=$0}else{print line; old=$2; line=$0}} END {print $0}' | less
```

It's output will be:

```
22,0,0,0.0,0
23,4,0,0.0,4
24,402,0,1.0,402
25,0,0,1.0,0
```

I suppose R is powerful language which should handle such tasks, but I've found only questions regarding calling awk scripts from R etc. How to do this in R?

Comment: You can use something like `dat[!duplicated(dat[,2]),]`

Comment: @docendo discimus You should make that an answer.

Comment: What if "0" reappears in row 25? Do you want to return it again or only once in the whole data set?

Comment: @docendodiscimus I made a comment about this in the answer indeed.

Comment: @docendodiscimus return it again.

Comment: See my comment at the @nrussell answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding the update to your question, a more general solution, thanks to @nicola:

```
Idx.first <- c(TRUE, tbl$orig[-1] != tbl$orig[-nrow(tbl)])
##
R> tbl[Idx.first,]
#    ord orig pred as o.p
# 1    1    0    0  1   0
# 23  23    4    0  0   4
# 24  24  402    0  1 402
# 25  25    0    0  1   0
```

---

If you want to use the **last** occurrence of a value in a run, rather than the **first**, just append `TRUE` to @nicola's indexing expression instead of prepending it:

```
Idx.last <- c(tbl$orig[-1] != tbl$orig[-nrow(tbl)], TRUE)
##
R> tbl[Idx.last,]
#    ord orig pred as o.p
# 22  22    0    0  0   0
# 23  23    4    0  0   4
# 24  24  402    0  1 402
# 25  25    0    0  1   0
```

---

In either case, `tbl$orig[-1] != tbl$orig[-nrow(tbl)]` is comparing the 2nd through nth values in column 2 with the 1st through n-1th values in column 2. The result is a logical vector, where `TRUE` elements indicate a change in consecutive values. Since the comparison is of length n-1, pushing an extra `TRUE` value to the front (case 1) will select the first occurrence in a run, whereas adding an extra `TRUE` to the back (case 2) will select the last occurrence in a run.

---

**Data:**

```
tbl <- read.table(text = "ord,orig,pred,as,o-p
1,0,0,1.0,0
2,0,0,1.0,0
3,0,0,1.0,0
4,0,0,0.0,0
5,0,0,0.0,0
6,0,0,0.0,0
7,0,0,0.0,0
8,0,0,0.0,0
9,0,0,0.0,0
10,0,0,0.0,0
11,0,0,0.0,0
12,0,0,0.0,0
13,0,0,0.0,0
14,0,0,0.0,0
15,0,0,0.0,0
16,0,0,0.0,0
17,0,0,0.0,0
18,0,0,0.0,0
19,0,0,0.0,0
20,0,0,0.0,0
21,0,0,0.0,0
22,0,0,0.0,0
23,4,0,0.0,4
24,402,0,1.0,402
25,0,0,1.0,0",
header = TRUE,
sep = ",")
```

Comment: Just seeing the comment by @docendo discimus, that solution is a little more concise and may be preferable.

Comment: Please feel free to add it to your answer

Comment: I'd also add something like `df[ c(TRUE,df$orig[-1]!=df$orig[-nrow(df)]),]` that may be more general and similar to what OP wrote in awk. Infact, if the `orig` column is not ordered, the result might differ (only unique values are taken within your approach and the @docendodiscimus 's one, while it seems to me that a row must be taken not if it is the first occurrence, but just if the values is different from the previous one). +1 of course.

Comment: So this is for 1nd script right (you are missing: 25,0,0,1.0,0 aren't you)? Would be possible to briefly describe how this work? Thank you

Answer (score 4):

For the (updated) question, you could use for example (thanks to @nrussell for his comment and suggestion):

```
idx <- c(1, cumsum(rle(tbl[,2])[[1]])[-1])
tbl[idx,]
#   ord orig pred as o.p x
#1    1    0    0  1   0 1
#23  23    4    0  0   4 2
#24  24  402    0  1 402 3
#25  25    0    0  1   0 4
```

It will return the first row of each 'block' of identical values in column `orig`.

- `rle(tbl[,2])[[1]]` computes the run lengths of each new (different than previous) value that appears in column `orig`
- `cumsum(...)` computes the cumulative sum of those run lengths
- finally, `c(1, cumsum(...)[-1])` replaces the first number in that vector with a 1, so that the very first line of the data will always be present

Comment: Nice, I was just working that out. I think you want something like `c(1, cumsum(rle(tbl[,2])[[1]])[-1])` for the indexing though, right? Otherwise you will be using row 22 instead of row 1 for the first observation of `0`.

Comment: So this is for 2nd script right? Would be possible to briefly describe how this work? Thank you

Comment: @Wakan Tanka `idx.first <- c(1, cumsum(rle(tbl[,2])[[1]])[-1])` applies to the 1st script (finding the first occurrence). Docendo's other approach `idx.last <- cumsum(rle(tbl[,2])[[1]])` applies to your second script (finding the last occurrence).